# Create graphs and charts in Java Swing application using MySql ResultSet data

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graph, charts

I have heard of JfreeChart but is there any general steps for using data returned from an SQL query to create graphs and chart.

I have an application that shows as a menu option "Analytic's", this Jframe window uses complicated query to retrieve data using business logic but i want to then display this data in a more viable way (rather than a long Jtable result). How can i filter my data and create a graph for the user to analyze?

Comment: JFreeChart is probably a decent way to go. You state that you've heard of it, but have you considered exploring it in greater detail and if not, why not?

Comment: i could not find any great examples and the API documentation wasn't really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are in search... I think that there is no better tool for designing and generating reports and graphs from your database than [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport). It offers a very consistent GUI, and gives you all support necessary to start creating business graphs from your database data.

The produced report is dynamic. Can be embedded  into any application. The reports can be exported as PDF, XML, XHTML, .doc, .odt and more ways. One can pass variables to the report at run-time like from-to Dates, code-id's etc.

iReport is built on top of [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports). It is free and open source.

Let me make also clear that i am not in any way affiliated with iReport!  :-)

Comment: this is very interesting. After i create a report, is it possible that that report will change as my data changes and can this be linked to a button_click event?

Comment: Absolutely! You can embed the report to any application and export your report in multiple ways. You can also pass variables to your report like from-to Dates, code-id's you name it... It built on top of JasperReports. Free and open source.

Answer (score 1):

Check [java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/CatalogChart.htm](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/CatalogChart.htm) for a lot examples.

Comment: This is great, im going to seriously consider JfreeChart. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can fill your own dataset based on your ResultSet.  But if you are query is returning results close enough to what you are loading into your dataset you can just use the [JDBCCategoryDataset](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCCategoryDataset.html) from JFreeChart.